# PHP/Javascript Select listner

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Oke thanks for taking the time to read my question.

i have a db were i store clients and licenses.

now in my php code i want to assign license to clients so what i want to make a select where you choose your license type like "windows 10".
then the other select next to it has to be filled with the answer of a query which are all the unassigned license keys for windows 10.

but i cant really do javascipt and i believe i need to do this partly with javascript so can anybody help me?

the code i have

```
        <tr>
            <td data-th="license Type">
                <select name="typeid">
                    <?php foreach ((new RecursiveArrayIterator($sthtypes->fetchAll())) as $k=>$row):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['t_id']?>"><?php echo $row['t_name']?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td data-th="License Key"><select name="license">
                    <?php foreach ((new RecursiveArrayIterator($sthlicences->fetchAll())) as $k=>$row):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['l_id']?>"><?php echo $row['l_key']?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </select></td>
            <td data-th="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
```

hope i gave enough information.

Comment: Show your attempt at least; you don't need JavaScript to make this possible by the way.

Comment: well the selects are no problem but i dont know how to let one listen to the other

Comment: Like I said, at least show what you have done.

Comment: i edited it a little

Comment: Okay, looking at this I don't see what you're trying to achieve: do you want  some sort of way of watching what is chosen so you can edit things? If so, JavaScript is needed and it will need to link to PHP. You can use `AJAX` to create a sort of `Listener` where, `onchange` it sends the value to the PHP file and then you can return a response which then the JavaScript can do something with. If this is what you need, let me know and I'll make a detailed answer for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer I will look it up and if i need more help or it works then i will post again

Comment: I answered it for you :)

Comment: so i did a little research and now i have the question is it possible to have the javascript send the id of the selected value. to the same php file. so i can put the $id in the query

Comment: Once the page has loaded, you cannot add PHP to it. You can only use AJAX for background processes so send the request to a seperate PHP handler, do your query there and then return the query to the Javascript for you to work with. Use my answer - it should do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Listeners` as such by using `AJAX`. The `change` event which you can attach to your `<select>`, by giving it an id, can fire a function which then sends the data to the `PHP` file and then returns a response.

**ie, javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $( "#select" ).change(function() {
      var cur = document.getElementById("#select").value;
      $.get( "example.php", { sendparam: cur } )
         .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
         });
   });
});
```

**References:**

[JQuery .change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) 
[JQuery .get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

**example PHP File:**

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['sendparam'])):
   echo 'this will be alerted every time its changed!';
endif; ?>
```

**Note:**

The `sendparam` in the jQuery function is the `Request` that is being sent, the `cur` in the jQuery function is the data being sent. When we are `alert`ing the data (response) it alerts the page source so ensure you have a blank page and only output what you want the alert to pick up!

**You do not have to alert the response, you can use it in many ways! ie:**

```
<script>
// inside the .done function
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;
</script>

<span id="output"></span>
```

Hope this helped!